# Why should use "apply"?

Tags: javascript

This snippet is cut from Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja.

```
function log() {
    try {
        console.log.apply( console, arguments );
    } catch(e) {
        try {
            opera.postError.apply( opera, arguments );
        } catch(e){
            alert( Array.prototype.join.call( arguments, " " ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Why should I use apply and what's the difference between `console.log.apply(console, arguments)` and `console.log(arguments)`?

Comment: The documentation should some up how apply is special: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply (hint: it does something special with the *array-like thing* [see notes] supplied as a parameter)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have

```
function log() {
    console.log.apply(console, arguments);
}
```

and call it like `log('foo');` then that translates to `console.log.apply(console, ['foo']);` which is equivalent to `console.log('foo');` which is what you want.

If you defined it like

```
function log() {
    console.log(arguments);
}
```

instead then `log('foo');` would be equivalent to `log(['foo']);` which is not what you want.

Comment: So, in a nutshell, `apply` allows you to pass a function a single array of arguments _as if_ they were different arguments.

Answer (score 38):

In this case, the log function may accept any number of arguments.

Using `.apply()`, it doesn't matter how many arguments are passed. You can give the set to `console.log()`, and they will arrive as individual arguments.

So if you do:

```
console.log(arguments)
```

...you're actually giving `console.log` a single `Arguments` object.

But when you do:

```
console.log.apply( console, arguments );
```

...it's as though you passed them separately.

Other useful examples of using `.apply()` like this can be demonstrated in other methods that can accept a variable number of arguments. One such example is `Math.max()`.

A typical call goes like this:

```
var max = Math.max( 12,45,78 );  // returns 78
```

...where it returns the largest number.

What if you actually have an Array of values from which you need the largest? You can use `.apply()` to pass the collection. `Math.max` will think they were sent as separate arguments instead of an Array.

```
var max = Math.max.apply( null, [12,45,92,78,4] );  // returns 92
```

As you can see, we don't need to know in advance how many arguments will be passed. The Array could have 5 or 50 items. It'll work either way.

Comment: Actually, in Firebug you may use console.log(arguments) as well, and this will lead to *almost* the same result. But I'm not sure about other browsers.

Comment: @kirilloid: Yes, sort of. Firebug and Chrome will display the content of the Arguments object, but it is still treated as one argument. You'll loose the benefit of multiple arguments like if you do: `log('value was %s',str);` where `str` is a variable containing a value you want to incorporate into the string. Instead of `"value was theValue"`, you'll get `['value was %s','theValue']`

Comment: @user113716 - why is the first argument to `Math.max.apply` `null`?

Comment: I get everything except one thing, when you call console.log.apply(x,y), does it actually call the console.log function n times, where n is the amount of indices in the array? Or is it called just once with the values concatenated or something?

Answer (score 7):

The `apply` function changes the value of `this` in the callee as well as letting you pass an array for the arguments.

For example, if you want to pass an array as arguments to a function:

```
function foo(value1, value2, value3) {
    alert("Value 1 is "+value1+".");
    alert("Value 2 is "+value2+".");
    alert("Value 3 is "+value3+".");
}
var anArray=[1, 2, 3];
foo(anArray); // This will not work. value1 will be anArray, and value 2 and 3 will be undefined.
foo.apply(this, anArray); // This works, as anArray will be the arguments to foo.
```

Or, another use: changing `this`:

```
function Foo() {
    this.name="world";
    this.sayHello=function() {
        alert("Hello, "+this.name);
    };
}
var foo=new Foo();
foo.sayHello(); // This works, as this will be foo in foo's sayHello.
var sayHello=foo.sayHello;
sayHello(); // This does not work, as this will not be foo.
sayHello.apply(foo, []); // This will work, as this will be foo.
```

Comment: In this case, the `this` is the same either way.

Comment: Your comment is misleading, the actual reason for using apply is another. * I didn't downvoted your answer -- just explained ;-)

Comment: +1 for stating: "The apply function changes the value of this in the callee"

Answer (score 6):

Let's discuss some background, why `apply` exist specially when we have `call` method with similar syntax.

First we need to understand some topics:

**Variadic function:**

> In computer programming it is a function which can accept any number
>   of arguments.

**Data structure is JavaScript:**

In javascript if we are dealing with data than most commonly used data structures is array, and in most cases we get data in the form of array.

Now if we are executing any variadic function in  javascript than our call will look like this -

`average` is a variadic function, and its call will look like,

```
average(1,2,3);
average(1);
average(3,5,6,7,8);
```

and if are getting data in array format(in most of the cases we will get data in array format for Variadic functions), than we need to call our function like -

```
average(array[0],array[1],array[2],array[3],.... and so on)
```

What if we got an array with length 100 items, do we write it like this ?

No, We have `apply` method, which was designed just for this purpose.

```
average.apply(null,array);
```

Comment: Why not accept argument in form of array in function and just call function abc like abc([1,2,3]) , and  handle array in function accordingly? Why so much complexity?

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(arguments)` would send a single argument to `console.log`, the array of arguments passed to your log method. `console.log.apply(console, arguments)` sends the possibly multiple arguments as multiple arguments instead of a single array.