# Best way to search through an Object containing multiple objects and arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have tried a couple of methods using indexOf and if (x in y) none of which seem to do exactly what I want.

I need to pull through several objects and find a specific number / timestamp / Date depending on the object. Here is a screenshot of the console of my Object.

Any thoughts?
[image]

Specifically when I first get the data I extract all the Timestamps (posted on date / time) from the API Response(s). Using that Array of timestamps I am trying to find the most recent posted object from all the responses.

Here are some more screen captures:

Twitter `created_at` timestamp
[image: Twitter created_at timestamp]

Tumblr `timestamp`
[image: Tumblr timestamp]

and my dates array
[image]

And my code used to pull the information and sort it.

```
//AJAX CALLS
$.when(
    //Bitter Syndrome
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        cache: false,
        url: "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/"+bittersymdrome_tumblr+"/posts/?api_key="+tumblr_apiKey,
        success: function(data){
            delete data.meta; delete data.response.blog;
            blogs.content.push(data);
        }
    }),

    //moundsMusic Tumblr
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        cache: false,
        url: "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/"+moundsmusic_tumblr+"/posts/?api_key="+tumblr_apiKey,
        success: function(data){
            delete data.meta; delete data.response.blog;
            blogs.content.push(data);
        }
    }),

    //GateWayDrugSTL Tumblr
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        cache: false,
        url: "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/"+gatewaydrug_tumblr+"/posts/?api_key="+tumblr_apiKey,
        success: function(data){
            delete data.meta; delete data.response.blog;
            blogs.content.push(data);
        }
    }),

    //GateWayDrugSTL Twitter
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        cache: false,
        url: "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?user_id="+gatewaydrug_twitter,
        success: function(data){
            blogs.content.push( data );
            /*var time = data[0].created_at;
            gwdtwDate = Date.parse(time)/1000;*/
        }
    })
).done( function(){
    //Get and Sort Dates most recent first.
    for(var i=0;i<blogs.content.length;i++){
        if(!blogs.content[i].length){
            for(var e=0; e<blogs.content[i].response.posts.length; e++){
                blogs.dates.push(blogs.content[i].response.posts[e].timestamp);
            }
        } else {
            for (var e = 0; e<blogs.content[i].length; e++){
                var time = blogs.content[i][e].created_at;
                gatewaydrug_twitter_date = Date.parse(time)/1000;
                blogs.dates.push(gatewaydrug_twitter_date);
            }
        }
    }
    blogs.dates.sort(function(a,b){return b-a});
    console.log( blogs );

    for(var i=0,len=blogs.dates.length; i<len;i++){

    }
});
```

[Here](http://thehivestl.com/test/) is a live link to a test server where you can view the object in your browsers console: http://thehivestl.com/test/

Comment: You should post the code using the Blockquote.

Comment: Can you be more specific to what you're looking for? What number/timestamp/date?

Comment: What code would you like?

The Objects are generated from API calls to Tumblr and Twitter, I just simply delete a few unnecessary values from the service's response and place them into my own Object.

Comment: Could you please post (shortened) JSON var dumps instead of console screen shots?

Comment: @Bergi Im sorry, I don't exactly know what you're looking for? I can make the code live if you'd like the view the console data? Here is a link to a test server, the main object is displayed in the console: http://thehivestl.com/test/

Comment: Just a plain-text [JSON string](http://json.org/) instead of that image. Thanks for the link to the demo, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix different object types in the same array, but normalize them before. Also, you should not need to use a global `blogs` variable, instead use the Deferreds properly.

```
function handleTumblrResponse(data) {
    delete data.meta;          // actually, you don't
    delete data.response.blog; // need those
    var resultdates = [];
    for (var e=0; e<data.response.posts.length; e++)
        resultdates.push(data.response.posts[e].timestamp);
    return resultdates;
}
function handleTwitterResponse(data) {
    var resultdates = [];
    for (var e = 0; e<data.length; e++){
        var timesting = data[e].created_at;
        var date = Date.parse(time)/1000;
        resultdates.push(date);
    }
    return resultdates;
}
$.when(
    // those get… functions are the plain ajax calls, no success handlers
    getBitterSyndromeAjax().then(handleTumblrResponse),
    getMoundsMusicTumblr().then(handleTumblrResponse),
    getGateWayDrugSTLTumblr().then(handleTumblrResponse),
    getGateWayDrugSTLTwitter().then(handleTwitterResponse)
).done(function(bitterSyndrom, moundsMusic, drugsTumb, drugsTwit) {
    // concat the four arrays to one
    var dates = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arguments);
    dates.sort(function(a,b){return b-a});
    // do something with the timestamps
});
```

Btw, I'm quite sure Date.parse cannot handle that odd Twitter format. Instead, use

```
function fromDateString(str) {
    var res = str.match(/(\S{3})\s(\d{2})\s(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)\s(?:([+-])(\d\d)(\d\d)\s)?(\d{4})/);
    if (res == null)
        return NaN; // or something that indicates it was not a DateString
    var time = Date.UTC(
      +res[9],
      {"Jan":0,"Feb":1,"Mar":2, …, "Dec":11}[res[1]] || -1,
      +res[2],
      +res[3],
      +res[4],
      +res[5], 
    );
    if (res[6] && res[7] && res[8]) {
        var dir = res[6] == "+" ? -1 : 1,
            h = parseInt(res[7], 10),
            m = parseInt(res[8], 10);
        time += dir * (h*60+m) * 60000;
    }
    return time;
}
```

Comment: This works great and is more clear / less code than my method, but I have a couple of questions: **1)** can you explain this line of code: var dates = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arguments); **2)** I was using the global _blogs_ to hold all the data from the multiple Tumblr Blogs and Twitter's response as well as all the timestamps. Is that not a good use for the global object?

Comment: 1) Using [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) is in here just the same as `[].concat(bitterSyndrom, moundsMusic, drugsTumb, drugsTwit)`.

Comment: 2) I don't think so. The global object would be accessible only after it was filled within an asynchronous task, and anything that uses it would need to be a callback on that task. Then why don't we call back with the actual value, instead of the information that it was placed somewhere? Of course you can put more arguments in there than only the timestamps.

Comment: So, you're saying then with this dates array I should use those timestamps to then go back to Tumblr or Twitter and say "give me the posts / tweets with this time stamp" instead of storing all the data in my function?

Comment: No. I said "store them in the function, not in the global scope". As you didn't told us what you want to do with the data, and did use only the dates in your sample code, I did only pass the timestamp arrays to the callback.

Comment: Hey again, I am still having some difficulty with this code, it seems like a clean and simple mark down, but I can't wrap my head around that chunk of code I added in the first comment. Maybe a little more explanation if you don't mind?

Comment: Which chunk of code? What part of my code do you not understand, the (Deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) and [`then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/) (formerly known as `pipe`)?

Comment: I am sorry, I meant this section:
var dates = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arguments);

I understand that the function is getting 'arguments' from either Twitter or Tumblr functions defined earlier, but I don't know what the prototype or apply call(s) actually do.

Comment: The [`concat` method of arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) is a function they inherit from `Array.prototype` (simple prototypical inheritance). For `apply`, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988645/why-should-use-apply)