# console.log.apply() and Math.max.apply()

Tags: javascript

I have read from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988645/why-should-use-apply) that in this function

```
function log() {
    console.log.apply(console, arguments);
}
```

it works like if the arguments are passed to console.log() **separately**, does it mean that when calling log([12,24,2])it can be interpreted as below?

```
console.log(argument[0]);
.
.
.
console.log(argument[n]);
```

If that was the case, what happened to the below line of code?

```
var max = Math.max.apply( null, [12,45,92,78,4] );
```

Why in this case the `arguments` is **not parsed separately**?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding you, your premise is incorrect. Calling `console.log.apply(console, [12, 24, 2])` is the same as `console.log(12, 24, 2)`.

Comment: can you read the second answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988645/why-should-use-apply , what does it mean by `...it's as though you passed them separately.`?

Comment: @Blake: In the context of research effort: Have you tried executing `console.log.apply(console, [12, 24, 2])` and `console.log(12, 24, 2)` in your debugger console to see what you get?

Comment: yes, gives [12,24,2] , I think I misunderstood the meaning of`separately` in that post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Separately" means *as separate arguments* to the function, not as as separate function calls.

As evan so bluntly put it:

> .. your premise is incorrect. Calling console.log.apply(console, [12, 24, 2]) is the same as console.log(12, 24, 2).

Thus `Math.max.apply( null, [12,45,92,78,4] )` is [roughly] equivalent to `Math.max(12,45,92,78,4)` and results in 92 - the expansion happens along *arguments*, not invocations. The behavior is consistent across all function calls, be it `console.log` or `Math.max`.

---

See [Function.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) for more details.

> The apply() method calls a function [once] with a given this value and arguments provided as an array (or an array-like object).